# PHP stripping out \t to insert tab

Tags: php, nginx

For some reason my server is ignoring "\t" -- yes I am using double quotes.

When I echo out a string like "abc\tdef\tghi" the "\t" is shown as a small "HT" with the "H" slightly smaller and above the "T"

Oddly, "\n" works and gives me a new line.

Not sure if this is an issue with PHP, NGINX, or something else, any ideas?

Comment: this looks like a character code issue ...

Comment: `␉` is a Unicode graphic symbol for representing control characters.

Comment: Does the page specify what encoding the browser should use? How does it appear in the source of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the the **escape character** instead the *escape sequence*. This works like a charm and you don't neet to worry about anything.

Let's say you have something like this:

```
$text = "First\tSecond\tThird\t...";
echo $text;
```

Replace it with this:

```
$text = "First\x09Second\x09Third\x09...";
echo $text;
```

Please note that using 'single quotes' with escape characters will get you '\x09' instead a real tabulator!

A list of all escape characters can be found in php.net manual:
[PHP.NET escape characters](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double)